# Dynamic conditions on ActiveRecord association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations, conditional-statements

I've got a model restaurant and a model closingdays. Each Restaurant has_many closingdays. Closingdays have a date-attribute.

How can I create a scope which shows me all open restaurants for today (all Restaurants with no closingday-record for this day)?

Thanks a lot!

Chris

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly how you're storing the days of the week in your table (text? numbers? etc), but you can pass a lambda to a named scope - so you could do something like this:

```
named_scope :open_today, lambda {  joins(:closing_days).where('open_day = ?', Time.now.wday) }
```

Not tested- but it should get you pointed in the right direction.

Comment: Each closingday-record has a date attribute, which stores a real date-object. Closingdays don't relate to weekdays, they are for special days like xmas, etc.
The problem I have with a query like yours is, that I get the restaurants multiple times, one record for each closingday-record. But I need only a clean collection of restaurants which are open today.

Comment: @ChrisCrown Hrm, that is interesting - you could group by restaurant id, but that seems like sort of a hack - I'll think about it a bit more.

Comment: I now made it this way:

scope :open, lambda {|date|
  joins(:closingdays).where("closingdays.date != ?", date).select("distinct(restaurants.id), restaurants.*")
}

But it's still unrailish I think...